# ADV manager error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am very much interested in developing android apps, I installed android studio and jdk. I created a new project but when I opened the AVD manager i got an error message

"Your computer doesn't support hardware accelerated virtualization (VT -x or SVM)".

Please help me out, I am completely new to android studio and I have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Install

> intelhaxm-android

which available in your SDK

> "SDK\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager"

if it can't install then enable intel-virtulization from your OS BIOS

Hope it work for you !

Comment: Intel HAXM package is installed in Android studio(Intel  x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM  installer))...still I am facing the problem...Is intel processor required in the system?. I have AMD processor

Comment: Has it something to do with Hyper-V